# Carrying alcohol deep into the wood?

Tags: history, storage, alcohol

**Carrying alcohol deep into the wood?**

A few friends of mine are going for a two week camping outing deep into the woods. As always they would like to carry with the something to drink at camp.

Thus my question: **What are some of the traditional methods of carrying alcohol into the forest and what would be the typical form of alcohol people would carry on their person, prior to 1900 AD?**

I would like to limit this question to a historical time frame of prior to 1900 AD if possible. It would be cool to see how this was done in the past. This also avoids the let’s go and party idea.

Answer (score 4):

A bottle made of leather seems to have been commonly used, for example in [Ivanhoe](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/82/82-h/82-h.htm), by Walter Scott

"The hermit only replied by a grin; and returning to the hutch, he produced a leathern bottle, which might contain about four quarts. He also brought forth two large drinking cups, made out of the horn of the urus, and hooped with silver." (Chapter XVI)

Comment: didnt he also ask what form of alcohol?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen bottles of liquor strapped to dogs.  My understanding is that whiskey or rum could be packaged in a small barrel/cask or in an earthenware crock that would be surrounded by a lot of straw, and, chances are, that this vessel would be carried by a beast of burden.

I haven't seen many historical accounts of carrying liquor on your person deep into the woods -- you can't carry enough to share very well as it is just too heavy and bulky.